# Should I reply to job queries I'm not interested in at the moment?

Tags: career-development, recruitment

From time to time I get unsolicited job queries, mostly through social networks like LinkedIn. Sometimes they are quite interesting and offer jobs in big respectable companies. But at the moment, I'm not interested at all in changing my job. Should I reply to such an interesting offer, just saying politely something like "the job is interesting, but at the moment I'm not considering changing my job"? Or just ignore it?

What do recruiters expect in such a case and what is considered polite? And is there any real benefit making contact with a recruiter in this case? Perhaps to have better prospects if I'd ever apply in the future for the company?

Comment: My question isn't about avoiding recruiters. It's about possibly relevant job queries.

Answer (score 3):

If the job is a good fit (or, at the very least, the recruiter is speaking to ME directly) then I always reply with a "Thanks, but no thanks". If the job is particularly perfect or the message particularly personal then I put a little more effort to say the same thing.

On the other hand, if I'm clearly being targeted based on random keywords, or the job has clear requirements that I obviously don't meet then I ignore them completely on the presumption that any help the recruiter will give me in future will be purely by chance. I also doubt these recruiters keep a particularly close eye on who they've contacted.

Sometimes it's not quite clear which camp they fall into it, so I'll tend to reply quickly.

Finally, phone calls always get a response because of the additional effort on their part.